# how to copy a directory with all inside contents to another directory?

Tags: android, adb

I want to copy a directory with all inside contents to another directory with ***dd*** command but It does not works. this is a sample:

```
 #shell dd if=/data/local/tmp/dir1 of=/data/local/tmp/dir2
```

and error message is:

```
 /data/local/tmp/dir2: cannot open for write: Is a directory
```

Can you help me?!

Comment: try with super user `sudo` and check permission of the folder where you wanna copy

Comment: dd reads files, not folders. As it is, that's not the proper way to write files to the start of a drive. You need to create a FAT32 partition first and then use cp to copy the contents over

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy a shell script to android out folder and execute it during boot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782156/copy-a-shell-script-to-android-out-folder-and-execute-it-during-boot)

Answer (score 1):

> dd works on the file you specify, making it able to copy data between devices, or from a device to a file. This is commonly used for moving data if devices specifically are involved (create an iso image from a cd-rom disc for example: dd if=/dev/cdrom of=mycdrom.iso), or backup raw devices (sometimes used in RAC databases: dd if=/dev/raw/raw1 of=device_raw1)
>
> cp is used for duplicating file content to a new file or to a new location. things you specifically want there are preservation of ownership, timestamp and mode (rights), and being able to recurse the operation (=being able to copy directories).

Try this command :

```
cp -r /data/local/tmp/dir1/* /data/local/tmp/dir2
```

Comment: I am using a htc phone (desire 700) with android 4.1. when I am using cp command, I see "sh: cp: not found" message :(